# Android Sender App getting timeout when trying to connect to Chromecast

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

I am writing an Android App which is playing YouTube videos.  I am working on adding Chromecast support to my app.  I learnt from various questions posted on Stack Overflow that YouTube SDK does not provide direct APIs to cast videos from your own app.  Following the suggestions provided, I wrote my own custom receiver and have published it too.  However, when I am calling launchApplication from my app, I am always getting status as 15 in onResult.

```
Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, APP_ID).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult applicationConnectionResult) { }
}
```

I learnt that 15 means Timeout.  But my receiver does get launched and I am able to see my HTML page getting loaded on TV when I connect to Chromecast through app.

```
    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder().addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(APP_ID)).build();
    mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
    mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback();
```

As my lauchApplication call fails, my sendMessage is not able to send the required signal to the Chromecast.

I am very new to chromecast and I have limited experience in working on it's integration with android app.  I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me, what could be an issue.

Comment: Since you are using a custom receiver, it is not possible to say what you are doing incorrectly. When you call launchApplication, how does your receiver respond back to the sender?

Comment: I haven't aded any custom status callback at receiver end.  Even my receiver is just a basic version where it is expected to play a hard-coded youtube video when a message is received.  Can you please tell me how I can modify my receiver to send a response back to server? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to read through https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver to get a better feel for what is happening and how you can customize various things.

Comment: Thanks Ali.  I found few issues with the customer receiver HTML file that I had written.  Fixing that, I could establish communication between my sender and receiver. The timeout primarily was happening because of some crashes observed in loading receiver.   Remote debugging helped in resolving the issues.  Thank you.