# Android Sender App getting timeout for DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID, when trying to connect to Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am working on adding Chromecast support to my app.

I have gone through : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/#0

Link for app from code lab : https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cast-videos-android/archive/master.zip

I'm able to cast videos using sample app, but in same app if I set the Receiver Application ID to DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID then I'm getting error 15 in SessionManagerListener callback.

```
            @Override
            public void onSessionStartFailed(CastSession session, int error) {
               //error =15 
            }
```

Following is CastOptionsProvider from code lab (read code comment):

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id)) // Here,I'm trying to use DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID = "CC1AD845"  
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that error 15 means session timeout. I'm not able to get any working example with DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID.

Thanks in advance.

I have also referred the thread , [Android Sender App getting timeout when trying to connect to Chromecast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076298/android-sender-app-getting-timeout-when-trying-to-connect-to-chromecast?rq=1)

Comment: Please file a bug so that Cast support team can investigate further: √=https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: Thank you @LeonNicholls , I have filed the bug to Cast support team.

Answer (score 0):

Android TV's Google cast receiver version was at factory version. After updating Google Cast Receiver it solved problem. Refer following link for more details...

https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7438776?hl=en-IN